# filter_input with 0 returns false

Tags: php, filter-input

I'm using filter_input now and I want it to return true on every number (0-9) and false on non-numbers (a-z, A-Z etc..)

Now, I use this script (just an example script but the idea is the same):

```
<?php

$i = filter_input(INPUT_GET, 'i', FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT);

if ($i)
{
    echo 'good';
}
else
{
    echo 'bad';
}
```

If I use 1-9 as GET variable (so like `test.php?i=1`), it shows `good`.
If I use a-Z as GET variable (so like `test.php?i=a`), it shows `bad`. So far so good.

But if I use 0 as GET variable, it shows bad as well. The variable can be 0 and should be true when the GET variable is 0.

Can anybody explain me why 0 returns false? I mean the GET variable is set and 0 is a number. Is it just because 0 is a falsey value?

Comment: That returns bad as well for 0.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`0` is a *falsey* value in PHP. `if (0)` is `false`.

Further, you're using the *sanitisation* filter, which will basically never fail. You want to use **`FILTER_VALIDATE_INT`** to *validate* whether the input is an integer.

Further, `filter_input` returns either `false`, `null` or `0` here. They're all equally *falsey*, meaning `== false`. You need to explicitly distinguish between them:

```
$i = filter_input(INPUT_GET, 'i', FILTER_VALIDATE_INT);

if ($i === null) {
    echo 'value not provided';
} else if ($i === false) {
    echo 'invalid value';
} else {
    echo 'good';
}
```

Comment: This doesn't work, when I use 0 or a-z or I leave it empty it still returns good.

Comment: @Joshua See addition.